# I have a large xml file in which contains multiple records. I want to get the records one by one as separate xml files using postgresql query

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I tried with xpath and it shows no errors but it doesn't give the result. It only returns an empty array.

```
WITH tbl(p_xml) AS ( SELECT text_xml :: xml FROM Test.test_xml ) 
 SELECT (cast (xpath('//service-repair-order-history/text()', p_xml) as text[]))     
FROM   tbl
```

I have a large xml file in which contains multiple records. I want to get the records one by one as separate xml files using Postgresql query and also I need to count the number of records too.